# How to push objects in php?

Tags: php

I have this empty array:

```php
$newRow = [];
```

I need somehow push this object into `$newRow`:

```php
$newRow = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));
```

But if I do it this way, it always overwrite an array. Methods like `array_merge` or:

```php
$newRow = (object)array_push((array)$newRow,(array)$this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));
```

Are useless because it always sends me an error `Call to undefined method stdClass::fetchAll()`.

Full code if you need:

```php
public function filter($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)
{
    $newRow = [];
    
    $statuses = [
        'dodano' => $showActiveOnly,
        'nedodano' => $showNotAdded,
        'casdodano' => $showHalfAdded,
        'storno' => $showDeclined,
    ];

    foreach ($statuses as $status => $addFilter) {
        if ($addFilter) {
            $newRow = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));
        }
    }

    return $newRow ?: $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
}
```

This is a func where fetchAll is

```
public function getFiltered($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, $showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)
{
    return $this->filter($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, $showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for $newRow[] = $myNewRowToBeAdded;  ?

Comment: "always get error with fetchAll". Please [edit] your post to include the full error

Comment: Yes i think, i just need to push somehow this `$this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));`  into $newRow but do not overwrite

Comment: @DiegoDeVita it also not working i got an error Call to a member function fetchAll() on array

Comment: `array_push($array, $newitem)` is equivalent to `$array[] = $newitem` .. and by the way it doesn't return the new array but it just changes the input array. So you don't have to overwrite the $newrow variable with its result or you will change its value with a number and that's maybe why you have an error when trying to fetch values from it (not sure because I didn't get that part clearly). The value returned from array_push is the number of elements in the array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php but it's hard to say if you have other problems there..that's for sure one

Comment: Your still lacking code for the complete picture. You don't have a function call fetchAll(), added more content to my answer.

Comment: The `filter` method returns what exactly? An array? An object? If it is an object, does it contain a method called `fetchAll`? Where do you check that? Your code is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does have several issues. I will now try to explain to you what improvements you can make to your code to avoid errors during execution.

### It 's all about return types

The first big issue in your code are return types. Your `filter` function returns either an array or the result of the `fetchAll` method, which can be either an array or something completely different. Your error message suggests that there may also be stdClass objects as a result here. Different return types are always a mess. You should avoid that.

The following example is shortened and demonstrates the power of type hints. Type hints can avoid errors like you 're experiencing right now.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

use Exception;
use PDO;

class Example
{
    protected PDO $database;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->database = $pdo;
    }

    protected function filter(string $param1, string $param2, string $param3): array
    {
        // result container for database rowsets
        $result = [];
    
        // some logic here that selects data from the database and pushes it 
        // into the result container
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT blah FROM blubb WHERE yadda = :param";
            $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('param', $param1);
            $stmt->execute();

            foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT) as $row) {
                 $result[] = $row;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // error handling - so important
        }
        
        // the result array and nothing else will be returned
        return $result;
    }

    public function getFiltered(string $param1, string $param2, string $param3): array
    {
        return $this->filter($param1, $param2, $param3);
    }
}
```

Have you noticed what happend here? The `filter` method returns only arrays. The `fetchAll` database method will be executed in the `filter` method only. The return type will not be messed up. It 's just an array of database rowsets.

If you want to return two different things a possible solution could look like the following example. But trust me, this is ugly a f.

```
protected function filter(string $param1, string $param2, string $param3): PDOStatement|array
{
    $result = [];
    $stmt = ...; // instance of PDOStatement with fetchAll method
    ...
    return $result ?: $stmt;
}

public function getFiltered(string $param1, string $param2, string $param3): array
{
    $result = $this->filter(string $param1, string $param2, string $param3);

    return ($result instanceof PDOStatement) 
        ? $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT)
        : $result;
}
```

Kids! Do not try the above shown at home!

### Collections with PHP

The above shown example class stores the found rowsets in an `$result` array. That 's fine so far. Depending on how many resultsets you want to store in that array, this can be very slow and consuming a hell of memory. A better solution are collections like ArrayObject or SplObjectStorage.

```
$row = [  
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'blah',
];

$collection = new ArrayObject();
$collection->append($row);
```

The advantages: Optimized memory consumption on iteration because of internal use of yielding and iterators and an object orientated interface.

### Conclusion

Your code ends up in error messages, because your `filter` function returns different things like arrays or objects. Your `getFiltered` method awaits an object, that has a `fetchAll` method, although your `filter` method returns an array or somewhat completely different, that does not have a `fetchAll` method.

If you want to use a method on the result of another method, just make sure that exactly this one object is returned, or check the return value to see if it is indeed the expected object.

Just keep things simple and stupid and don 't try to overinvent something simple, e.g. because you think method chaining looks cool or something even more senseless. Check your return values!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not really adding, you are currently overwriting.

```
<?php

class AddToArray
{
    public function filter($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, $showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)
    {
        $newRow = [];

        $statuses = [
            'dodano' => $showActiveOnly,
            'nedodano' => $showNotAdded,
            'casdodano' => $showHalfAdded,
            'storno' => $showDeclined,
        ];

        foreach ($statuses as $status => $addFilter)
        {
            if ($addFilter)
            {
                $newRow[] = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));
                // or :
                // array_push($newRow, $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status)));
            }
        }
        return $newRow ? : $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Either use the short hand method: `$array[] = ''` or the dedicated function, `array_push($array, $NewEntry)`.

You're not using `fetchAll()` correctly, which is out of the scope of the original question.

Here is the documentation of `fetchAll()`:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

For you, you should probably call it like this:

```
$rows = $this->db->table(self::TABLE_NAME)->where(array('status' => $status));
$rows->execute();
$results = $rows->fetchAll();
```

Comment: for some reason i have an error Call to a member function fetchAll() on array when i use $newRow[]

Comment: `public function getFiltered($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, $showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)
    {
        return $this->filter($showActiveOnly, $showNotAdded, $showHalfAdded, $showDeclined)->fetchAll();
    }`  this is the function where fetchAll is but i think there is no problem

Comment: That line of code, is not in your question, so either add that or rephrase the question.

Comment: added into my question

Comment: @Angua And last, should i do it in filter function or in getFiltered? Btw thank you very much for your help

Comment: Got same error Call to a member function execute() on array